# Switching a side menu to off-canvas/top-menu with Foundation

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, zurb-foundation

I am trying to achieve result like [this](http://themes-pixeden.com/demos/levo/index.html) using Foundation 5.

I want the top bar and side menu to act exactly like in that template. A side menu with icons and text.

I can use "show-for-large-up" class for text, so it hides in medium leaving behind only icons. But the issue is having side menu which switches to offcanvas menu in small screens and becomes part of top menu. I am finding this hard to achieve.

Comment: I clarified the body of the question and rewrote the title to explain what you're trying to do. I suspect the foundation tag is wrong, by the way, and should be zurb-foundation; please double-check.

Comment: thanks Nathan. Not sure which tag you where talking abt.

Comment: Hey Nathan are you sure thats a off-canvas menu? coz the link is just a normal left menu. check this http://zurb.com/patterntap even they have use normal left menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either duplicate the content to be both on side menu and top bar, and set show-for-large-up on the side menu and hide-for-large-up on the top menu.

Another option is to append elements dynamically from the side bar to the top bar using JavaScript / jQuery

Comment: thanks, i dont want to duplicate the code for menus. Let me try with jquery append and then i will post the codes here.

Comment: I couldnt convert a left menu to top menu, only way is to go with duplicate content. also do you know how to get this effect on hovering over left menu http://zurb.com/patterntap
Whats it called?

Comment: actually never mind i used jquery mouseenter and mouseleave and got that  effect.

Comment: Cool, I was just about to post an answer

Comment: Hi Tomer, if its a different approach please add. Always good to learn something new.